# How to fix "No keyword with name '0=' found" in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I am a newbie in Robot framework. I want to run multiline IF Statement but I am getting below error:

Error :

> "0= Evaluate, ${G_NO_OF_RECIPIENTS}+${NUMBER_OF_CALLEE} FAIL  No
>   keyword with name '0=' found. "

This error is occurring for variable `${REM_COUNT}`

Code :

```
     Log                ${G_NO_OF_RECIPIENTS}
     Log                ${NUMBER_OF_CALLEE}
     ${REM_COUNT}      Set Variable    ${0}
     Run Keyword If     "${NUMBER_OF_CALLEE}" != "${G_NO_OF_RECIPIENTS}"      Run Keywords
     ...    ${REM_COUNT}=           Evaluate        ${G_NO_OF_RECIPIENTS}+${NUMBER_OF_CALLEE}
     ...    AND     Log            "ITS WORKING"
```

Similar piece of code works somewhere else, only thing was I did not use  multiline if statement in it. I appreciate if I get help on this.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Run Keywords` does not allow variable assignment inside its block, e.g. this line:

```
Run Keywords
 ...    ${REM_COUNT}=           Evaluate        ${G_NO_OF_RECIPIENTS}+${NUMBER_OF_CALLEE}
 ...    AND     Log            "ITS WORKING"
```

is illegal syntax. It tried to substitute `${REM_COUNT}` with its value (0), and to run it - thus the failure.

`Run Keyword If` does pass any return values, so you can do it this way:

```
${REM_COUNT}=     Run Keyword If     "${NUMBER_OF_CALLEE}" != "${G_NO_OF_RECIPIENTS}"
                      ...                  Evaluate       ${G_NO_OF_RECIPIENTS}+${NUMBER_OF_CALLEE}
                      ...     ELSE         Set Variable   ${REM_COUNT}   # if the condition is False, leave the variable to its previous value
Run Keyword If     "${NUMBER_OF_CALLEE}" != "${G_NO_OF_RECIPIENTS}"    Log            "ITS WORKING"
```